# How to exclude Primary key while Insert in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key

I have a table having many columns.
The primary key is auto-generated.
When a record is inserted through Entity Framework (.Add(),and .SaveChanges()) methods, it should ignore inserting primary key. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its primary key in DB and is identity () then you don’t need to worry about auto increment EF will handle it whereas if it’s a column other than primary key  that you want to have auto-generated then you can using **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]** in the entity.

I will recommend you to 1st Create entity ,  2ND add  and then   save.

```
Var entity  = this.DataSet.Create();
this.DataSet.Add(entity);
this.dataContext.SaveChanges();
```